# compiler says member function not defined however it is included in the header file c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Compiler says member function not defined however it is included in the header file c++. I have about 10 functions and one function find_similar the compiler says undeclared variable on the tester implementation file. The purpose of the program is to check the validity of two entries from the main.cpp/test file. I made a program which checks the entries from the test file.

CarInventory.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include "CarInventory.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;



void CarInventory::resetInfo()

{

    m_type = nullptr;

    m_brand = nullptr;

    m_model = nullptr;

    m_year = 0;

    m_code = 0;


    m_price = 0;

}

CarInventory::CarInventory()

{

    resetInfo();

}

CarInventory::CarInventory(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model, int year, int code, double price)

{

    resetInfo();

    setInfo(type, brand, model, year, code, price);

}

CarInventory::CarInventory(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model)

{

    resetInfo();

    setInfo(type, brand, model, 2022, 100, 1);

}

CarInventory::~CarInventory()

{

    delete[] m_type;

    delete[] m_brand;

    delete[] m_model;

}

CarInventory& CarInventory::setInfo(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model, int year, int code, double price)

{

    if (type == nullptr || brand == nullptr || model == nullptr || year < 1990 || code < 100 || price < 0)

    {

        resetInfo();

    }

    else

    {

        delete[] m_type;

        delete[] m_brand;

        delete[] m_model;

        m_type = new char[strlen(type) + 1];

        strcpy_s(m_type, sizeof(type), type);

        m_brand = new char[strlen(brand) + 1];

        strcpy_s(m_brand, sizeof(brand),  brand);

        m_model = new char[strlen(model) + 1];

        strcpy_s(m_model, sizeof(m_model),  model);

        m_year = year;

        m_code = code;

        m_price = price;

    }

    return *this;

}

bool CarInventory::isValid() const

{

    return m_type != nullptr && m_brand != nullptr && m_model != nullptr && m_year >= 1990 && m_code >= 100 && m_price >= 0;

}

bool sdds::CarInventory::find_similar(CarInventory car[], const int num_cars)
{
    return false;
}

void CarInventory::printInfo() const

{

    std::cout << "|" << std::setw(12) << m_type << "|" << std::setw(18) << m_brand << "|" << std::setw(18) << m_model << "|" << std::setw(6) << m_year << "|" << std::setw(6) << m_code << "|" << std::setw(11) << m_price << "|" << std::endl;

}

bool CarInventory::isSimilarTo(const CarInventory& car) const

{

    return m_type == car.m_type && m_brand == car.m_brand && m_model == car.m_model && m_year == car.m_year;

}

namespace sdds {

    bool find_similar(CarInventory car[], const int num_cars)

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++)

        {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < num_cars; j++)

            {

                if (car[i].isSimilarTo(car[j]))

                {

                    return true;

                }

            }

        }

        return false;


    }
}
```

Header File

```
#ifndef CARINVENTORY_H
#define CARINVENTORY_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

namespace sdds {
class CarInventory {
    char* m_type;
    char* m_brand;
    char* m_model;
    int m_year;
    int m_code;
    double m_price;
    void resetInfo();
public:
    CarInventory();
    CarInventory(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model, int year, int code, double price);
    CarInventory(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model);
    bool isSimilarTo(const CarInventory& car) const;
    ~CarInventory();
    CarInventory& setInfo(const char* type, const char* brand, const char* model, int year, int code, double price);
    void printInfo() const;
    bool isValid() const;
    bool find_similar(CarInventory car[], const int num_cars);

   };
 }
 #endif
```

main/tester file

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<iomanip>
        #include "CarInventory.h"
        using namespace std;
        using namespace sdds;

        int main()
         {
         const int num_cars = 6;
          bool invalid_data = false;
          CarInventory cars[num_cars] = {
       {},
    {"suv", "volvo", "xc90"},
    {"Truck", "Ford", "F 150", 2021, 105, 55000},
    {"Sedan", "BMW", "M550i", 2022, 101, 91000},
    {"Truck", "Tesla", "Cybertruck", 2021, 102, 65000},
    {"Sedan", "BMW", "M550i"}
};

if (cars[2].setInfo("SUV", "Volvo", "XC90", 2019, 109, 80000).isValid()) {
    cout << "Information was set correctly!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Information was set incorrectly!" << endl;
}
if (cars[1].setInfo("SUV", "Volvo", "XC90", 1234, 1, 1).isValid()) {
    cout << "Information was set correctly!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Information was set incorrectly!" << endl;
}


cout << setw(60) << "----- Car Inventory Information -----" << endl << endl;;
cout << "| Type       | Brand            | Model            | Year | Code |     Price |" << endl;
cout << "+------------+------------------+------------------+------+------+-----------+" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++) {
    if (cars[i].isValid())
        cars[i].printInfo();
    else
        invalid_data = true;
}

if (invalid_data) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(60) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "*  WARNING: There are invalid data in the inventory!      *" << endl;
    cout << setfill('*') << setw(60) << "*" << endl;
}
if (find_similar)(cars, num_cars)) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << setfill('+') << setw(60) << "+" << endl;
    cout << "+  WARNING: There are similar entries in the inventory!   +" << endl;
    cout << setfill('+') << setw(60) << "+" << endl;
}
return 0;
  }
```

Error message:
[image]

Comment: If allowed, replace all of the character arrays with `std::string` and watch your stress level go way, way down.

Comment: Regardless of the function declarations and definitions,  the test code in `main()` does `if (find_similar)(cars, num_cars))` which is a syntax error for the compiler to choke on.

Comment: An unrelated problem: `strcpy_s(m_type, sizeof(type), type);`  - `type` is a `const char*` and its size is a constant expression. It'll always be the same (usually 4 or 8) no matter how long the string is. Do as @user4581301 suggested. Use `std::string`s instead

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid call:

```
if (find_similar)(cars, num_cars)) {
```

1. The syntax is wrong.
2. You need a `CarInventory` instance since the function is not `static`.

```
CarInventory foo;
if( foo.find_similar(cars, num_cars) ) {
```

I think you should make `find_similar` a non-member function instead. Just move the declaration outside of the class:

```
class CarInventory {
    // remove this:
    // bool find_similar(CarInventory car[], const int num_cars);
};

// declare this:
bool find_similar(CarInventory car[], const int num_cars);
```

The free function `sdds::find_similar` (that you've already defined in `CarInventory.cpp`) will then be found via ADL (*argument-dependent lookup*) - even if you don't do `using namespace sdds;` first. You also need to remove the definition of `CarInventory::find_similar` in `CarInventory.cpp`.

Finally, correct the call in `main`. You will not get this program to work without changing `main`:

```
if(find_similar(cars, num_cars)) {
```

Comment: Hey the main tester file cannot be changed, and i was told to put find_similar on a different namespace

Comment: @JohnanthanGibbs The main tester file is wrong. It _must_ be changed. `find_similar` is in the namespace in which the class is defined since it's a member function. You can't move a member function to a different namespace than the class to which it belongs is defined in. If you make `find_similar` a free function, sure, then it'll work - but the syntax error is still there

Comment: If you can't change the "main tester file" you are screwed.   It is flat out wrong, and that cannot be fixed by changing the class definitions.   You need to lodge a report of a flawed test case (specifically, a test case that CANNOT be compiled in any circumstances).

Comment: You need to talk to whoever supplied that tester file. They could have some code, like a macro, you are not privy to and they could have  simply <expletive deleted>ed up. Mind you, using a hidden macro also falls under my personal definition of <expletive deleted>ing up.

Comment: In addition to `CarInventory::find_similar` the member function, there's also `sdds::find_similar` the free function. I'm not sure why the latter isn't being found.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, that free function _is_ found (via ADL if `using namespace sdds;` wasn't used) once the syntax error is corrected.

Comment: @JohnanthanGibbs Did you try to make the changes I suggested in the answer and did you fix the `strcpy_s` issues I pointed out?